# Concatenate multiple rows into one where the NULL values are without losing the other information?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I am wondering if it is possible to concatenate multiple rows in an ArcMap shapefile attribute table into one row based on shape length.

In the table below, I have created the fields "Form B1, Form B2, Form B3, Material B1, Material B2, Material B3". I have populated those values with information from the Zone, Component, Form and Material columns.

All 3 rows have identical geometry and are overlaid on top of each other. I want to combine them into one single row without losing the data.

For example, "Form B1" has been populated with information from:

- Zone B
- Component 1
- Form
- Material

"Form B2" with information from:

- Zone B
- Component 2
- Form
- Material

So my question is, can I merge/concatenate these 3 rows into one, and have the information fill in where the NULL value current is?

[image: ArcMap Attribute table]

Comment: Is it always 3 rows and the scenario of 1 row of data and 2 rows of null?

Comment: No. It either 1, 2 or 3 rows that need to be merged into one.

Answer (score 1):

Without your data and understanding all the nuisances of it my first thoughts are that you might want to explore a combination of using the Delete identical tool to reduce the rows down to one by the geometry and the summary statistics tool to pick out the non-null value using a suitable group by field, then you join the summary data to your reduces row data.